# How do I build a sense of wonder in my games?

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, tone

I guess this is part three of a series of questions, with [part I being on building tension](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/how-can-gms-evoke-the-tone-of-danger-in-an-rpg), and [part II being on building comedy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7685/building-a-good-comedy-adventure).

Greg Stafford has talked of his primary motivation as a gamemaster being the evocation of wonder in players. His Glorantha setting has any number of wonder-inducing features. For instance, Skyfall Lake, where the timeless realm of the gods joins the time-bound realm of mortals, is a great gash in the sky where the blood of a dead god falls as water into a lake.  The Cult of Nysalor is a metaphysical wonder, revolving around the sublime madness of an awakening that frees you from all moral and spiritual constraints and makes the choice between heroism and world-consuming evil a matter of one's attitude to one's own desires.

How can we get our players to be enraptured by our game's set pieces?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What is notable about [Glorantha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorantha) in terms of fictional worlds?  Its coherence. It has a extensive and richly detailed mythology and history designed to be as "realistic" (the sense of verisimilitude, as we have to point out in any RPG discussion even though it is always blatantly obvious).

It's interesting, if you research the term "[sense of wonder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_of_wonder)" it is primarily affiliated with science fiction. In fact, many articles on it say that wonder is [more possible in science fiction than in fantasy](http://io9.com/#!5671561/rationality-sets-science-fiction-apart-from-fantasy).

And why is this?  Because a fundamental grounding in reality is required for the cognition that makes a sense of wonder possible. Fantasy and magic, when used so that "we can just make up whatever crap we want," fail to accurately evoke a sense of wonder.

@LordVreeg is on the right track in terms of details and immersion, but the core value behind those is the fundamental sense that the setting is somewhere 'real,' which has its own consistency and rationality. Then, a specific element that is larger than life or incredible holds resonance for the reader. In "[Rhetorics of Fantasy](http://books.google.com/books?id=8nVglcu53QYC&dq=niall%20harrison&ie=ISO-8859-1&source=gbs_gdata)" the primary genres of fantasy that create a sense of wonder are described as portal and intrusion fantasy (which use our world as a backdrop for that contrast) and immersion fantasy (characterized by its rich, fully realized setting).

Therefore how you build a sense of wonder in your RPG is to have an internally consistent setting.  Not one where things are a way because 'the game rules say so,' or 'I made up something wacky one day' - but something that seems like a real, living, breathing world, so that then the immanence of revelation can generate an emotional response in the game's participants.

Comment: Totally agree that you connected those dots.  The cognition part is why detail matters.

Comment: Yes, internal coherence is one of the most important things in every setting, be it an rpg, a book, a movie or whatever.

Comment: Agreed. I think this is why the traditional intro to a fantasy RPG campaign, where the PCs all meet in a tavern, continues to be so attractive (well, aside from being evocative of Tolkien and the Prancing Pony Inn). The PCs begin the adventure immersed in a familiar, comfortable location that is real to them. It's a portal to the unknown. Wonderous monsters and magic, all that is weird and unnatural are distant rumors. The PCs sitting around a table in a bustling tavern, next to a roaring fire & perhaps musicians, reminds the players of sitting around a campfire listening to stories.

Answer (score 25):

Creating a sense of Wonder can be done in a few different ways, but there are a few ingredients that help to stop a player dead in their tracks.

- Details-Great ideas and powerful
  prose can be destroyed by fuzziness
  of the background.  I know it is
  boring, but the background and detail
  of the setting provide the
  underpinnings and buttressing for the
  epic set piece.  For example, Tolkien Multiplied the impression the Mines of Moria makes when he forshadowed them
  with the information about Balin,
  mithril, thror, etc.  They are a
  deeper and more enduring 'Set Piece'
  because of how they fit into the
  details of the setting, as opposed to standing alone.
- Setting Expectations-Something is
  perceived as marvelous or unusual in
  the way it stands out from the rest
  of the world.  When I took classes in
  fiction writing back in the dark
  ages, they cautioned against
  everything being the biggest,
  strongest, coolest...in Setting
  design, the strongest sense of wonder
  is created by creating a realistic,
  baseline expectation of normalcy.
  If you numb them with superlative
  experiences, the set piece won't have
  the same effect.
- Immersion- The GM's best friend, and
  tied to the detail part, is that
  wonder is created more powerfully
  when the player can see through the
  eyes of the character to some degree.
  The player sees Skyfall lake as a
  well-written set piece; but the more
  the player can see through the eyes
  of the character that is breathing in
  the air of that place and seeing the
  sun's light glint off it; the more
  amazing the impression will be.
- Delivery- It may sound ridiculous,
  but practice and rehearse the
  delivery of the initial
  view/discovery of said set pieces.
  You get one chance to make this first
  impression, and if you are on your
  game and delivery smoothly and
  impressively, it is a far different
  effect from a dead tired monotone.

Comment: I hesitate about Details, the first point: this is fixing a style of gamemastering I try to be loose about, but I see the connection to Immersion. The other three I think are excellent points.

Comment: It has been the sticking point in many game design and setting design conversations.  I don't want to say it (or any of them) cannot be worked past by being brilliant in other areas...But I stand by my assertation that in every case, if all other things are equal, we'd see that the level of detail aids in creating the sense of wonder.

Comment: I totally agree - detail light is a "valid style of GMing" but it's not conducive to a sense of wonder.

Comment: +1 for making all good points. About the detail... I think it would be more accurate to say that if the setting -lacks- sufficient detail, a sense of wonder is difficult to achieve. No matter how wonderous a setting is, if it only exists in the imagination of the DM, the players won't be impressed. I like the concept of foreshadowing by telling a story about a setting, as Tolkien did.

Answer (score 2):

The [current Legends and Lore post](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20111004) by Monte Cook deals with the mystery of magic items, and how it's diluted by their commonness. He suggests that when *"[...] treasure ends up being a part of the characters' advancement track, not a reward"*, you lose the wonder of having magic items. It's just expected to have magical gear, and everyone has it, so it's no different from nobody having any, and it's not notable. Having a vorpal sword is not that big a deal if everyone else is up to their eyeballs in other magical loot.

Though this is D&D 4E centric, the general point stands, I think. Make your rewards not common, and they will keep on being wondrous.